# How to create JPA Specification for multiple tables?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, specifications

I had entities User, BlockUnit, Block and Unit as Follows. 
User has ManyToMany relation with blockunit.

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @ManyToMany
    private Set<BlockUnit> blockUnits;
}
```

```
@Entity
public class BlockUnit {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = Block.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "block_id")
    private Block block;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = Unit.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "unit_id")
    private Unit unit;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
}
```

BlockUnit has OneToOne relation with Block and Unit.

```
@Entity
public class Block {
    @Id
    private Long id;
}

@Entity
public class Unit {
    @Id
    private Long id;
}
```

**How should I create the JPA criteria specification for above in order to select user's having Block ID and Unit ID?**

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Like you create an SQL selection of `BlockUnit`.`user` from `BlockUnit` where `BlockUnit`.`unit` = ? and `BlockUnit`.`block` = ?

Comment: Yes.. @Zorglube